# Python: Split using lambda and keeping second value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Jugador': {0: 'A. Gignac', 1: 'N. Ibáñez'},
              'Equipo': {0: 'Tigres UANL', 1: 'Pachuca'},
              'Equipo durante el período seleccionado': {0: 'Tigres UANL', 1: 
              'Pachuca'})
```

I am trying to split the Jugador column and only keeping the last name by using the following code:

```
df.Jugador.apply(lambda name: name.split(' ')[1])
```

when I run the code I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Expected output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Jugador': {0: 'Gignac', 1: 'Ibáñez'},
          'Equipo': {0: 'Tigres UANL', 1: 'Pachuca'},
          'Equipo durante el período seleccionado': {0: 'Tigres UANL', 1: 
          'Pachuca'})
```

Comment: If there is no second name, then it will cause error.

Comment: also `apply` should be avoided when possible. to split columns, it's better to use the vectorized `str` methods: `df.Jugador.str.split().str[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is causing as you are trying to find the `1` index of the whole name. If there is no any surname, `1` index will be out of range. So, it is the reason for the error.

Try this:

```
df.Jugador = df.Jugador.apply(lambda name: name.split(' ')[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Still can't get my head around it though. From my understanding when I split using ' '  A. Gignac will be split into index 0 = A. and index 1 = Gignac, no?

Comment: If you are splitting using a space, yes it splits into two names, if there is space in the whole name.